# classList.add has stopped my code from running. I can't figure out why. Can you?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, frontend

```js
var p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");

var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;

var gameOver = false;

var winningScore = 5;

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(!gameOver){
  p1Score++;
  if (p1Score === winningScore)
    p1Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
  }
  p1Display.textContent = p1Score;

});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(!gameOver){
  p2Score++;
  if (p2Score === winningScore)
    p2Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
  }

  p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

});
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1><span id = "p1Display">0</span> to <span id = "p2Display">0</span></h1>
<p>Playing to: 5</p>
<input type="number">
<button id="p1" type="button">Player One</button> 
<button id="p2" type="button">Player Two</button> 
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
```

The `p2Display.classList.add("winner");` lines on my two functions has stopped my code from working.

If you remove it the code works fine.

However, I need that line of code in order to complete this game.

Is there a reason why it's stopping my game from working?

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What kind of error? Which browser?

Comment: little tip - if you indented your code properly, it would be a lot easier to see your mistake

Comment: @Pete  I'd go even one step further, if you use an editor with Linting, it would be super easy to spot the mistake.  Might be nice if SO had an auto linting for code snippets.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening and closing brackets around the statements in the if block:

```
if (p1Score === winningScore)
    p1Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
```

So, only the first statement is considered part of the `if` block, while the second statement `gameOver = true;` executes regardless. As a result, the game gets over with the first click event.

Here's the updated snippet with opening and closing brackets added around the if block:

```js
var p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");

var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;

var gameOver = false;

var winningScore = 5;

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    p1Score++;
    if (p1Score === winningScore)
    {
      p1Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
  }
  p1Display.textContent = p1Score;

});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    p2Score++;
    if (p2Score === winningScore)
    {
      p2Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true;
    }
  }

  p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

});
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scoreKeeper.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="p1Display">0</span> to <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1>
  <p>Playing to: 5</p>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="p1" type="button">Player One</button>
  <button id="p2" type="button">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scoreKeeper.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with your curly braces.

you need to remove the opening curly brace here: if(!gameOver){

and you need to add a curly brace: if (p2Score === winningScore)
(in both eventlisteners)

```
p2Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
if(!gameOver)
    p2Score++;

if (p2Score === winningScore){
    p2Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
}

p2Display.textContent = p2Score;})
```

otherwise your execution order of the lines is messed up